# Finding a certain text, copying everything below the text in another workbook under the same text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro which checks in "Sheet1" for certain texts. For example "Head 1" and "Head 2". If he finds those texts, every cell below should be copied under the same "headtext" in "Sheet2".

Sheet1:
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2:
[image: Sheet2]

Result after Sheet1 got copied in Sheet2:
[image: the result after Sheet1 got copied in Sheet2]

I have a first approach but I don't know how to continue. Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim FindH1 As Range
        With Range("A:DD")

        Set FindH1 = .Find(What:="Head 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not FindH1 Is Nothing Then

            '???

        End If

    End With   
End Sub
```

Comment: so what you are actually after is copying the columnds for each header from sheet 1 to sheet 2 under the same headers?

Comment: Not for each, but for certain ones and the order in Sheet1 is different from Sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you, the code is explain so I guess you can go through it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    'You need Microsoft Scripting Runtime for this to work
    Dim HeadersSheet1 As New Scripting.Dictionary 'Store the column index for each header on sheet1
    Dim HeadersSheet2 As New Scripting.Dictionary 'Store the column index for each header on sheet2
    Dim arrHeaders As Variant 'store all the headers you want to copy
    Dim i As Long 'for looping purpose
    Dim LastRow As Long 'Last row for each column on sheet1
    Dim Col As Long 'Get last column  each sheet1
    Dim C As Range 'Loop with cells is better with this

    arrHeaders = Array("Header1", "Header2", "Header3") 'here you input the headers you want to copy

    'First we store headers column index on sheet 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Col = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column on row 1 for sheet1
        For Each C In .Range("A1", .Cells(1, Col)) 'loop through the headers
            HeadersSheet1.Add C.Value, C.Column 'store the header name with it's column
        Next C
    End With

    'Then we store headers column index on sheet 2
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        Col = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column on row 1 for sheet1
        For Each C In .Range("A1", .Cells(1, Col)) 'loop through the headers
            HeadersSheet1.Add C.Value, C.Column 'store the header name with it's column
        Next C
    End With

    Dim lrow As Long 'last row on sheet2
    Dim Col2 As Long 'column on sheet2

    'Finally we loop through the headers we want
    For i = LBound(arrHeaders) To UBound(arrHeaders)
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
            Col2 = HeadersSheet2(arrHeaders(i)) 'find the header column on sheet2
            lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col2).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find the next blank cell on that header
        End With
        End With
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            Col = HeadersSheet1(arrHeaders(i)) 'find the header column on sheet1
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row on that header
            .Range(.Cells(2, Col), .Cells(LastRow, LastRow)) _
                .Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lrow, Col2) 'copy the range
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it out but it gives me an error at: HeadersSheet1.Add C.Value, C.Column 'store the header name with it's column

Comment: did you check the microsoft scripting runtime? what error is it giving? @DeltronR

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn't show me any specific error. The debugger jumps to the second HeadersSheet1.Add C.Value, C.Column

Comment: @DeltronR but if you get an error it gives you one, which is? add a screenshoot on your question with the error.

Comment: @DeltronR what happens if you press F5?

Comment: Runtime Error "457" @Damian

Comment: and what does the description of the error says? That is what i'm trying to know 4 comments above

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood you. It says: "This key is already associated with an element of this collection."

Comment: You have duplicated headers, check out both sheets and delete duplicate headers.

Comment: No duplicated Headers in my sheets. But nvm, I will look for another solution. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Then there are blank cells between the first column and the last. More than one.